# how to vertical align with different content

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/D35dJ/6/

Why when I have different content in paragraph .info change his vertical position, example in link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `vertical-align: top` to the `.info` div, and making it `display: inline-block` instead of just inline fixed it for me.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D35dJ/11/)

Answer (score 2):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/D35dJ/10/

I changed the display property of your both containers to table-cell. I Also added the property vertical-align. Now it should work!